# TinyGet with URL Parameters

Tags: load-testing

Anyone still using TinyGet?

When I pass a single query string parameter, everything works fine. As soon as I try to add a second param I get an error.

Here's an example of the error I'm getting:

C:\Program Files\IIS Resources\TinyGet>tinyget -srv:mydomain.com -uri:/Search/Results?q=food&pIndex=5 -loop:10
'pIndex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I've reviewed resources like http://code.google.com/p/toolsdotnet/wiki/TinyGet and I can't get this to work. Any ideas?

(PS: I tried tagging this "TinyGet" but I don't have enough rep, in case someone else wants to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer over at the IIS forums (http://forums.iis.net/p/1166670/1940071.aspx#1940071).

The ampersand must be escaped with the ^ character, so in this case the call would be:

C:\Program Files\IIS Resources\TinyGet>tinyget -srv:mydomain.com -uri:/Search/Results?q=food^&pIndex=5 -loop:10

Answer (score 0):

You could also just wrap the uri in quotes.